# Map() not loading in Content View

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to follow the WWDC23' MapKit tutorial. Its simple enough to import MapKit and then declare the Map(). From there, I expect to see a Map preview off to the right, however, im only seeing the grid lines. It looks like the map isnt loading, so im assuming it cant find my location or something small like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Map()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you just have to move it around or zoom in and out in simulator.

Comment: I have tried setting my location in debug, I have tried zooming in, out, etc. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Your code works well for me, what system are you using and targeting? I'm on MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst.

Comment: Your code works on Xcode 15.2 M1 MacBook Pro in Xcode Previews.

Comment: Hi - thank you all for chipping in to help. All of my exp is in Web Dev, Windows, VSC, etc.. so i really appreciate it. I just purchased an M2 running Mac OS 14.0. Looks like I am running XCode 15.1 and targeting iOS 17.2.

Comment: Note, if your `default` new Mac position is (lat=0, lon=0), then you are in the ocean off the coast of west Africa, south of Ghana.
Keep zoomin out until you see some land.

Comment: I updated my MacOS, and everything is working fine now. Thank you!